esp32-c3 dropping bluetooth connection when connected to motor driver
I am trying to minimize parts when connecting an esp32-c3 with bluetooth and drive a motor. In one configuration, I have used a L298N as follows:
ESP32-C3 Mini    L298N Motor Driver
------------    -------------------
5V     <--------------- 5V OUT
GND    <--------------- GND
GPIO18 <--------------- IN1
GPIO19 <--------------- IN2
GPIO23 <--------------- ENA

Decoupling capacitors arriving today, which I hope to add to the esp32. When the motor is turned on, it drops the connection. I have also tried use a voltage regulator to the esp32, no decoupling caps, and see the same problem.

This isn't worth putting much thought into until the decoupling caps are installed.  That's certainly debugging step 1.

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

surely the esp has caps on the module if it takes in 5v, right? Are you sure your PSU can provide enough current to prevent a voltage drop?
